# Deletion of image from folder that is referenced to picture box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

sorry i have to rewrite this question as i did not get any update on my same question posted previously.

Below is the code where I'm inserting some data into Ms Access database in visual studio using vb. Net.

When i insert the data i also browse the image for that item and save into the folder that is located under project directory for universal access.

There is a datagridview which displays the data which was inserted to access  databas alog with the image in picture box. Whenever the the datagrid view selection is change it display the picure into picture box.

I am having a trouble when i want to delete the data along with image located in project folder as it show the error that 'file used by another process, cant be deleted'

Since i have referenced that image to my picture box, it can not be deleted directly. So here I'm looking for a solution which can display the clone of image in picture box instead of real object.

Below is my code

```
Public Class frmMainCetegory
Private Sub frmMainCetegory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
    Me.CenterToParent()
    Me.btnAddNew.Select()

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    Try

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.AddNew()
        Me.txtMainCategory.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try

        If Me.txtMainCategory.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Main Category Name!", vbInformation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.txtMainCategory.Text & ".jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Update(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.btnAddNew.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Try
        Dim MainCatName As String
        MainCatName = Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value

        If Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
            'check before delting, if this main category is used in sub category then It can not be deleted.
            Dim I As Integer
            I = frmSubCategories.TblItemSubCategoryTableAdapter.qryCountMainCategoryUnderSubCategory(MainCatName)
            If I > 0 Then
                MsgBox(MainCatName & " is used under Sub Category(s), Please Delete Sub Category(s) First!", vbOK)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        Me.TblItemMainCategoryBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Update(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)
        Me.TblItemMainCategoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PosDatabaseDataSet.tblItemMainCategory)

        'Delete the Main Category Image if this exists
        If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & MainCatName & ".JPEG") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & MainCatName & ".JPEG")
            MsgBox("Image Deleted Successfull")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Try

        Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Bitmaps(*.JPG, *.PNG, *.JPEG, *.BMP, *.TIF, *.GIF, *.TIFF)|"
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim img As String = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)
            Me.btnSave.Select()

        Else

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.SelectionChanged
    Try

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = DirectCast(Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG").Clone(), Image)
        ' Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG")

    Catch ex As Exception

        Me.imgMainCategoryImage.Image = My.Resources.imgEmpty 'if image path not found then select empty image

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click
    frmTable.Show()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Firstly, if someone doesn't answer your question, don't just repost it. Edit the existing question to make it better. Apart from that, I already answered your question elsewhere. If you just ignored the answer I provided there, why should anyone believe you won't just ignore what you're told here? As I already told you, if you call `Image.FromFile` then the file is locked until you dispose the file. You can't delete a locked file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Delete Image From Project Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780036/unable-to-delete-image-from-project-folder)

Comment: It's easier this way: `PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("Image Path")`, then `PictureBox1.Image.Dispose() File.Delete("Image Path")`. Otherwise, you have to handle the underlying stream and it's, maybe, not that simple to explain how it works under the hood. Note that, even if you dispose of the Image, the Bitmap won't disappear. You'll have to set `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing`. Or substitute it with another.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I apologize for asking the same question, I will keep a check on that going forward. But still nothing helped me. If i use Dispose before deleting then some time it work or some time not. This is the weird thing which i ever seen. I wasted my three days for doing simple where I add any image into picture box then save it to any location and then assign again to picture box and here i dispose the image if i want to delete, but it work sometime not always even picturebox.image=nothing doesn't work. Even I'm not sure whether we are on same page with this issue?

Comment: It will work if you do it properly. If it didn't work, you didn't do it properly. If you need us to help with that, you need to show us EXACTLY what you did and tell us EXACTLY what happened. Vaguery like "I tried and it didn't work" is no use to anyone.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't have to call `Image.FromFile` or `New Bitmap` and assign the result to the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`. You can also set the `ImageLocation` property or call the `Load` method and, in either case, just provide the file path and let the control create the `Image`. If you do that then there will be no lock on the file and thus you can delete it without issue. I'm not sure whether that applies to both `ImageLocation` and `Load` or just one but you can test that`.

Comment: You should still dispose the `Image` object when you're done though. ALWAYS dispose any objects you create that support it when you're done with them.

Comment: Hi Jimi, a big thanks to you for helping aroynd this. I used image.Location property and now its working fine and not locking the image. However i have not used. dispose property as without it, there is no issue i found. Thanks